# Help! The Minus Front in illustrator is not working properly!

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So i have this logo [image: before]

And when I use minus front this happens [image]

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I'm using Illustrator CC by the way

Comment: Weird... I can't explain why it ends up like that, but you might get better results if you take a copy, `outline stroke` each element, pathfinder `merge`, and *then* do the minus front with normal solid shapes with no strokes. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, i already tried that, and the letter also ends up distorted :(

Comment: Very strange! Can you add a screenshot of how it distorts the flattened / no stroke version? Is there anything in the `appearances` window when these are selected? (thinking there might be a distort effect or something?)

Comment: i hadn't tried flattening the dragon as well. It worked now! thank you for the tip!!!! :D

Comment: The people here are all very helpful

Comment: Cool, if you want you can post an answer to your own question showing what you did, and it might help others (and possibly earn you points `:-)`)

Answer (score 1):

Do the minus front with normal solid shapes with no strokes.